# How to solve this problem through dynamic programming approach?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was solving a very basic problem on arrays. The problem statement goes like this:

*A basketball court has been opened in SIS, so Demid has decided to hold a basketball exercise session. 2⋅n students have come to Demid's exercise session, and he lined up them into two rows of the same size (there are exactly n people in each row). Students are numbered from 1 to n in each row in order from left to right.*

*Now Demid wants to choose a team to play basketball. He will choose players from left to right, and the index of each chosen player (excluding the first one taken) will be strictly greater than the index of the previously chosen player. To avoid giving preference to one of the rows, Demid chooses students in such a way that no consecutive chosen students belong to the same row. The first student can be chosen among all 2n students (there are no additional constraints), and a team can consist of any number of students.*

*Demid thinks, that in order to compose a perfect team, he should choose students in such a way, that the total height of all chosen students is maximum possible. Help Demid to find the maximum possible total height of players in a team he can choose.*

For example if the input is:(First line contains the value of n, next 2 rows follow which contains the height of the students)

```
5
9 3 5 7 3
5 8 1 4 5
```

My approach was:

```
#These are global variables and functions. 

int arr1[n],arr2[n],sum=0,max=0;
void func1(i)
{
   if(i==n)
   {
      if(sum>max)
         max=sum;
      return;
   }
   sum+=arr1[i];
   for(k=i+1;k<n;k++)
      func2(k);
}

void func2(i)
{
   if(i==n)
   {
      if(sum>max)
         max=sum;
      return;
   }
   sum+=arr2[i];
   for(k=i+1;k<n;k++)
      func1(k);
}

#Caller module. In main
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   sum=0;
   func1(i);
}
```

This is my algorithm based on my logical reasoning. I have not coded it yet, will code it later. **So feel free to point out any logical errors in the code.**

I know this can be solved easily using **dynamic programming** approach and this algorithm is not quite it. **How will the functions look like in that case?**

As far as I can point out, the problem in this algorithm is I need to declare `arr1` and `arr2` globally whereas I get to know the value of n in the main function.

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, review, or tutorial resource.  If you clearly describe your algorithm, we can comment on that; if you show a functional problem with your code, we can help.

Comment: Asking us to code a DP solution for you is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `int arr1[n],arr2[n]` -- If `n` is a variable, this is not valid C++.

Comment: Your algorithm completely skips first player in second row (arr2[0]). Besides, `sum` shouldn't be a global variable, you need to pass it as an argument to `func1` and `func2`.

Comment: @KonstantinMurugov yes you are right I need to call `func2(i)` from main and compare the value with `func1(i)` and the greater one will be the answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have highlighted this problem in the question itself. I need to define a default size array and work in the 0-(n-1) portion of the array. That would be an unnecessary wastage of space.

Comment: @Prune I didn't ask to code a DP solution. There is a problem in designing the recursion step for the DP solution, which I haven't explicitly mentioned but it is understandable from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic programming would be quite straightforward here. We have two choices: Choose from A or skip, Choose from B or skip. Our bottom-up recurrence could look like:

```
// Choose from A or skip
m[i][0] = max(A[i] + m[i - 1][1], m[i - 1][0])
// Choose from B or skip
m[i][1] = max(B[i] + m[i - 1][0], m[i - 1][1])
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, B){
  let m = new Array(A.length + 1)

  for (let i=0; i<=A.length; i++)
    // [a or skip, b or skip]
    m[i] = [0, 0]

  for (let i=1; i<=A.length; i++){
    // Choose from A or skip
    m[i][0] = Math.max(
      A[i-1] + m[i - 1][1], m[i - 1][0])
    // Choose from B or skip
    m[i][1] = Math.max(
      B[i-1] + m[i - 1][0], m[i - 1][1])
  }

  return Math.max(...m[A.length])
}

var a = [9, 3, 5, 7, 3]
var b = [5, 8, 1, 4, 5]

console.log(f(a, b))
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't describe how it obeys "no consecutive chosen students belong to the same row"

Comment: But the subsequence A#1,skip,A#3 is not allowed either.  (If the utility is strictly non-negative, such as player height, then that sequence would always be dominated by A#1,B#2,A#3 which is legal.... but this sort of structurally-dependent "ricochet to meet the rule" deserves documentation)

Comment: Like I already said, it cannot give a final wrong solution if utility values (here, player heights) are strictly positive.  But the fact is that you're creating infeasible intermediate solutions and relying on domination to choose a feasible one... that to me is important to call out, lest a future change to the problem definition (introducing negative utility) allow an infeasible solution to be chosen as optimal.  Or, you could avoid creation of infeasible solutions in the first place, as @Gene does.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think that your code always takes i+1 element from array B if ith element is chosen from array A and vice-versa. But as far as I have studied the problem, I will have flexibility to choose anyone of the element from i+1 to n from array B if ith element is chosen from array A. It is due to this constraint, that I couldn't write the recursion step. Hope you can understand.

Comment: @Excelsior I don't believe so. For input `a = [9, 3, 10, 7, 10]` and `b = [-5, -8,  -1, -4,  -5]`, the code returns 18, which is A[0] + B[2] + A[4]. I would welcome an example where you believe the code is performing unexpectedly.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes you are right. I tried every possible combination and it worked every time. Great work. I understood the logic somewhat but it would be very helpful, if you can mention the underlying logic/theory/mathematics for the bottom up recurrence step so that it will help future visitors of this issue and myself too. Once again a wonderful approach.

Comment: @Excelsior the idea is that tracking the skips can be shared between the two states, `m[i][0]` and `m[i][1]`; but if we choose to use an element, we _must_ then switch to the other state. In other words, if there was a useful skip, it will be tracked in the other state, so we can safely switch to it when we choose an element.

Answer (score 1):

We can define 2 functions A and B. A(i) is the maximum height we can get by next choosing player with index i or greater from the first row.  B(i) is the same for the second row. Now we can write A in terms of B and B in terms of A. For example A(i) is the max over all indices k that are i or greater by choosing the k'th element from the first set plus the max we can get by choosing from k+1 or higher from the second. B(i) is symmetric:

```
A(i) = max_{k=i..n} a[k] + B(k + 1); A(n) = a[n]
B(i) = max_{k=i..n} b[k] + A(k + 1); B(n) = b[n]
```

The answer will be max(A(1), B(1)).

A simple way to go is just code this as it's written with 2 memoized functions. I'll use C rather than C++ with tweaking to use 0-based indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5
int a[] = {9, 3, 5, 7, 3};
int b[] = {5, 8, 1, 4, 5};
int Avals[N], Bvals[N];

int B(int i);

int A(int i) {
  if (i >= N) return 0;
  if (Avals[i]) return Avals[i];
  int max = 0;
  for (int k = i; k < N; ++k) {
    int val = a[k] + B(k + 1);
    if (val > max) max = val;
  }
  return Avals[i] = max;
}

int B(int i) {
  if (i >= N) return 0;
  if (Bvals[i]) return Bvals[i]; 
  int max = 0;
  for (int k = i; k < N; ++k) {
    int val = b[k] + A(k + 1);
    if (val > max) max = val;
  }
  return Bvals[i] = max;
}

int main(void) {
  int aMax = A(0);
  int bMax = B(0);
  printf("%d\n", aMax > bMax ? aMax : bMax);
  return 0;
}
```

I claim there's a way to replace the memoized recursion with simple loops that access the elements of Avals and Bvals in strictly decreasing index order, but I'll let you figure out the details. This result will be smaller, faster code.

Comment: I appreciate your approach. It's similar to my approach. I think that this problem lacks a concrete DP approach due to the fact that a DP problem needs a recursion step and recursion is "a function calling itself". Meanwhile I will go by this approach as the question setter only suggested to go by a DP approach. LOL

Comment: @Excelsior Of course this solution is a DP. A calls B and B calls A. This is called mutual recursion.

Comment: Oh okay! I have never used it so I didn't know that. Thank you for sharing your answer.